# Fetch only updated workflow YAML files using Github Actions API

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

Below is the link that I am using to list the repository workflows with GitHub API

```html
https://github.api.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/workflows
```

Here is my sample data:

```json
{
"total_count": 2,
"workflows": [
    {
      "id": 161335,
      "node_id": "MDg6V29ya2Zsb3cxNjEzMzU=",
      "name": "CI",
      "path": ".github/workflows/blank.yaml",
      "state": "active",
      "created_at": "2020-01-08T23:48:37.000-08:00",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-08T23:50:21.000-08:00",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/workflows/161335",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octo-org/octo-repo/blob/master/.github/workflows/161335",
      "badge_url": "https://github.com/octo-org/octo-repo/workflows/CI/badge.svg"
    },
    {
      "id": 269289,
      "node_id": "MDE4OldvcmtmbG93IFNlY29uZGFyeTI2OTI4OQ==",
      "name": "Linter",
      "path": ".github/workflows/linter.yaml",
      "state": "active",
      "created_at": "2020-01-08T23:48:37.000-08:00",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-10T23:50:21.000-08:00",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/workflows/269289",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octo-org/octo-repo/blob/master/.github/workflows/269289",
      "badge_url": "https://github.com/octo-org/octo-repo/workflows/Linter/badge.svg"
    }
}
```

I want to list the workflows which is updated between 2020-08-01 and 2020-08-10, so I used the below api link.

```html
https://github.api.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/workflows?updated_at:2020-08-01T00:00:00Z..2020-08-10T00:00:00Z
```

Even though this filter condition matches only one workflow, I get both the workflows listed. How do I list only the workflow which matches this criteria.

Comment: I don't think you can use the `updated_at` like this.. What you probably need to do instead is fetch everything and then filter with `jq`.

Comment: you are right. this filter condition is not working. can you give an example how to use jq in the api link

Comment: If your question now turns into "how to use jq", please open a new question and show what you have tried and how that didn't work.